# Existence of maximal subgroup of $G$ with the property of not containing $g\in G$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $g\in G$. Prove that if $g\neq 1$, then there exists a subgroup of $G$ which is maximal with respect to the property of not containing $g$.

I built a chain of subgroups $M_\lambda$ for $\lambda\in \Lambda$ (where each subgroup not contain $g$) partially ordered by inclusion, i try to use the **Zorn's lemma** 
 but since $G$ can be an infinite group, i don't know how to go on with the proof. Any ideas or hints? Thank you

Comment: Hint: The union of a chain of subgroups is a subgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't index by $\Bbb N$ since the chain may be uncountably infinite.

---

To use Zorn's lemma, you show that there is a subgroup not containing $g$, and you show that every chain of subgroups not containing $g$ has its union also being a subgroup not containing $g$.